# Paper View effect iPhone

Tags: iphone

I would like to create a  turn up page view with button under the view like the first image of this app:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ihandy-translator-pro/id402422247?mt=8

How can I do this "page peek" view, it works so if I press in the bottom right of the yellow pad is raised and the button are displayed. How can I do that? And how is this method of view called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view controller to hold the buttons, then present it modally using the `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` [modal transition style](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks, but i see that all page turn up, how i can have only a "peek"?

Comment: The `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` and `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown` animation transitions will flip all the way over, but the `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` transition style only obscures the lower half of the parent view controller. A good example of the `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` style is in the "Maps" app.